# How to add a column from another table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm starting to using SQL statements in my Oracle database XE (tables and relations made by me) and I'm having a hard time to understand how can I put a column from another table.

The example in this case is:

- I have two tables that are interconnected, `ORDERS` and `PRODUCT`.

In `ORDERS` there are the following attributes:

- `ORDERID` (defined as `Primary Key`), `PRODUCT_NAME` (a `Foreign Key` from the `PRODUCT` table) and `QUANTITY`.

In `PRODUCT` there are:

- `NAME` (defined as `Primary Key`) and `PRICE`.

I want to add a column that gets the `PRICE` from the `PRODUCT` table and insert it to the `ORDERS` table according to the `PRODUCT_NAME`, obviously.

How can I do it? 
Are there any workarounds?

Please, keep in mind that I'm a newbie and my knowledge is very limited.

Comment: Are you using an Order_Line table - with Product_Name, Quantity and Product_Price? The Orders table should be a header. Note use of singular names for tables - except for Orders (Order being an SQL keyword).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean with Order_Line

Comment: CREATE TABLE Order_Line (Order_id, Product_Name, Quantity) Put a UNIQUE index on Order_id, Product_Name. CREATE TABLE Orders(Order_id, Client_id, Order_Date,..... perhaps discount or other fields) PRIMARY KEY for Orders is Order_id). Just a suggestion.

Comment: Oh, I see, I have another table with this content, but with another name that we are used to use in our company. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Since nobody is answering I found a workaround for now here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/oracle-update-statement-with-inner-join but I have to run this script each time there is an INSERT in the ORDERS table. My goal is making this as automatic as possible.

Comment: And you can't use triggers to make updating automatic? I'd say they are the way to go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original question was:

> I want to add a column that gets the PRICE from the PRODUCT table and
>   insert it to the ORDERS table according to the PRODUCT_NAME,
>   obviously. How can I do it? Are there any workarounds? Please, keep in
>   mind that I'm newbie and my knowledge is very limited.

and the ultimate reply (after much communication through comments - see above), my response was

> And you can't use triggers to make updating automatic? I'd say they
>   are the way to go!

Which worked.

Answer (score -2):

you add column  to  orders table  using

```
alter table tablename  add  column  datatype
```

then

```
insert  into  orders(price) select  price from  product;
```